# Removing non-ASCII characters from file text

Tags: python, unicode

Python experts:

I have a sentence like:
    `"this time air\u00e6\u00e3o was filled\u00e3o"`
   I wish to remove the non-Ascii unicode characters.
   I can just the following code and function:

```
def removeNonAscii(s): 
    return "".join(filter(lambda x: ord(x)<128, s))          

sentence = "this time air\u00e6\u00e3o was filled\u00e3o"   
sentence = removeNonAscii(sentence)
print(sentence)
```

then it shows up: `"this time airo was filledo"`, works great to remove "\00.."
but when I write the sentence in a file, and then read it and make as a loop:

```
def removeNonAscii(s):
    return "".join(filter(lambda x: ord(x)<128, s))

hand = open('test.txt')
for sentence in hand:
    sentence = removeNonAscii(sentence)
    print(sentence)
```

it shows `"this time air\u00e6\u00e3o was filled\u00a3o"`
it doesn't work at all. What happens here? if the function works, it should not
be that way....

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working. It works fine for me.

Comment: what is your Python version?

Comment: Try to explicitly open the file with UTF-8 encoding (`open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8')`)

Comment: Python 3.5 is the version I'm running.

Comment: To Nick, thanks. But I just tried and still doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly is in the file? E.g. does the file *literally* contain "\u00e6" as 6 separate (ascii codepoint) bytes, rather than the utf-8 sequence for unicode char 0xe6?

Comment: The file could have more other ascii characters. But I am just stuck on this.... now I just assume the text file has the content exactly same as the sentence.

Comment: @Hsiang `\u00e6` in your code (a string literal) is very different than it being in the file. Try writing the sentence to a file then reading it back in your code: `open('test.txt', 'w').write("air\u00e6\u00e3o")` or something like that

Comment: I just upgraded Python to 3.4.3. I am using Jupyter. Is this a possible reason?

Comment: @Nick, thanks a lot. But I did try to use "hand = open('test.txt','w').write("air\u00e6\u00e3o")" and it shows error while doing the loop: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @Hsiang Try to understand what that code does. That expression doesn't return the file object, it simply writes a few characters to a file. Also, what kind of file are you opening?

Comment: @Roeland, the file is named "test.txt" and has a sentence "this time air\u00e6\u00e3o was filled\u00e3o" only.

Comment: @Hsiang the file should look like "this time airæão was filledão" if you open it up with some text editor; no escape sequences.

Comment: @Nick, Thanks. Did you mean that I did the open file and write, as you suggested: open('test.txt', 'w').write("air\u00e6\u00e3o")  Yes. the text content shows "airæão"

Comment: @Nick: I think you meant `codecs.open()`.

Comment: @martineau there's some difference between `io.open` (a.k.a. `__builtin__.open`) and `codecs.open`, but both seem to taken an `encoding` kwarg. I don't quite understand the subtleties though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that instead of having the actual `non-ascii` characters, the text in your file is actually displaying the utf-8 sequence for the character, ie instead of whatever character you think is there, it is actually the code `\u00--` and so when you run your code, it reads every character and sees that they are completely fine so the filter leaves them.

IF this is the case, use this:

```
import re
def removeNonAscii(s):
    return re.sub(r'\\u\w{4}','',s)
```

and it will take away all instances of '\u----'

example:

```
>>> with open(r'C:\Users\...\file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.sub(r'\\u\w{4}','',line))
this time airo was filledo
```

where file.txt has:

> this time air\u00e6\u00e3o was filled\u00a3o

Comment: It works! thanks! Does it work for all types of non-ascii characters?

Comment: @Hsiang There weren't any non-ascii characters in the file, or this *wouldn't* have worked to begin with. The file contained the literal characters ```\```, `u`, `0`, `0`, `e`, and `6` in sequence. As opposed to the single byte `\u00e6`

Comment: this doesn't actually replace non-ascii characters, it replaces anything that looks like a utf-8 representation of a unicode character. in reality, these are 6 separate characters