# Remove non ascii chars from a file using python

Tags: python

I have a scenario where the log files sent for analysis had some non ascii chars and ended up breaking one of the analysis tool which I have no control. So decided to clean up the log myself and came up with the following function this does the job except I end up skipping the entire line when I see those characteres. I
            tried going character by character for that line ( check the commented ) code so that only those chars can be eliminated  and save the actual ascii ones but couldn't succeed.
            Any reasons for failure of that commented logic and suggestion/solution to solve this problem?

sample line that failed:

> 1:02:54.934/174573**ENQ**Î**NULSUB**áy**NULEOT**/29/abcdefghijg

Function to read and remove the lines:

```
def readlogfile(self, abs_file_name):
    """
    Reads and skip the non-ascii chars line from the attached log file and populate the list self.data_bytes
    abs_file_name file name should be absolute path
    """
    try:
        infile = open(abs_file_name, 'rb')
        for line in infile:
            try:
                line.decode('ascii')
                self._data_bytes.append(line)
            except UnicodeDecodeError as e :
                # print line + "Invalid line skipped in " + abs_file_name
                print line
                continue
            # while 1: #code that didn't work to remove just the non-ascii chars
            #     char = infile.read(1)          # read characters from file
            #     if not char or ord(char) > 127 or ord(char) < 0:
            #         continue
            #     else:
            #         sys.stdout.write(char)
            #         #sys.stdout.write('{}'.format(ord(char)))
            #         #print "%s ord = %d" % (char, ord(char))
            #         self._data_bytes.append(char)
    finally:
        infile.close()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511317/removing-non-ascii-characters-from-file-text/33511747#33511747 this guys original code should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

decode takes another argument, what to do with bad characters. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Try this

`print "1:02:54.934/174573ENQÎNULSUBáyNULEOT/29/abcdefghijg".decode("ascii", "ignore")`

```
u'1:02:54.934/174573ENQNULSUByNULEOT/29/abcdefghijg'
```

and your code can be pared down to something like this

```
def readlogfile(self, abs_file_name):
    """
    Reads and skip the non-ascii chars line from the attached log file and populate the list self.data_bytes
    abs_file_name file name should be absolute path
    """
    with open(abs_file_name, 'rb') as infile:
        while True:
            line = infile.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            self._data_bytes.append(line.decode("ascii", "ignore"))
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to copy the actual text with special characters ? I believe there are some other characters I missed while copying and the parser still break with both the solution. @Dave_750

Comment: you might also try line.decode("ascii", "ignore").encode("ascii") if it is still fussy

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be proper way to handle offending lines on a character-by-character basis:

```
import codecs

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data_bytes = []

    def readlogfile(self, abs_file_name):
        """
        Reads and skips the non-ascii chars line from the attached log file and
        populate the list self.data_bytes abs_file_name file name should be
        absolute path
        """
        with codecs.open(abs_file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                try:
                    line.decode('ascii')
                except UnicodeError as e:
                    ascii_chars = []
                    for char in line:
                        try:
                            char.decode('ascii')
                        except UnicodeError as e2:
                            continue  # ignore non-ascii characters
                        else:
                            ascii_chars.append(char)
                    line = ''.join(ascii_chars)
                self._data_bytes.append(str(line))
```